# Problem with "semilogyaxis" in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've some trouble using the following code. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 x64 with (in this case) QTikZ and got this code by the `matlab2tikz` function, and the following example simply just don't work in QTikZ.

I'm almost sure that the error occurs, because of the combination of the log-scale and the "distance" from 0.1 to 100000. I got this impression, because of other cases which I could get work when excluding the "1". For those other plots I'd liked to plot a bit-error-rate (BER) so starting with 0.99 instead of 1 was a compromise I could live with, but here I need the range from 0.1 to 100000.

I would be really thankful, if anyone could give me any hint to get my plot drawn in log-scale.
Hope everybody could understand me, although of my bad language skills. ;-)

And here the not yet working code:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.1.3.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2011, Nico Schloemer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{semilogyaxis}[%
scale only axis,
width=4.52083in,
height=3.56562in,
xmin=1, xmax=9,
ymin=0.1, ymax=100000,
title={$\text{Test-Figure N}= 8$},
axis on top]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
mark=o,
mark options={solid}
]
coordinates{
 (1,10531.1)(2,2150.19)(3,258.407)(4,21.2681)(5,16.0093)(6,11.8044)(7,4.96487)(8,1.39658)(9,0) 
};

\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
mark=x,
mark options={solid}
]
coordinates{
 (1,11050.1)(2,39.3339)(3,7.92449)(4,2.50753)(5,0.906895)(6,0) 
};

\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Works for me with pgfplots v1.8. Maybe an update is needed for you.

Comment: If you are the same user as the one who posted an "answer" below, the StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).